# Document with custom bibliography driver compiling with babel 3.33 and biblatex 3.13a ; but not compiling with most recent package versions

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel

I am experiencing following situation:

I have **WE** copied below, that works with package combination:

- babel[czech] v. 3.33 from 2019/07/19
- biblatex v. 3.13a from 2019/08/31

but doesnt work with recent version of both packages. Compilation fails even before `biber` run with error `biblatex package: Patching babel failed` This error is entirely alien to me and in biblatex doc I cant find its resolution. I suspect that this state is (from data perspective) from 20.1.2020, which could point to update to v. 3.38 of `babel`

Sadly, I have only **WE** (not minimal), because I dont know which part is causing the recent incompatibility of my code with `babel` and `biblatex`; at least I hope that the version-localisation might suffice.

WE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage [czech] {babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{filecontents}

%definition of new entry type

\begin{filecontents}{speclegislation.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{speclegislation}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  document,
  short,
  number,
  year,
  title,
  paragraph,
  article,
  letter,
  sortkey,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[speclegislation]{
  document,
  short,
  number,
  year,
  title,
  paragraph,
  article,
  letter,
  keywords,
  sortkey,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, datamodel=speclegislation, refsegment=chapter, mincrossrefs=1, backref=true, backrefstyle=three]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{speclegislation}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{document}%
  \newblock
  \printfield{number}%
  \newblock
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{title}
  \newblock
  \printfield{paragraph} %
  \newblock
  \printfield{article} %
  \newblock
  \printfield{letter}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
    \map{
      \pertype{speclegislation}
      \step[fieldsource=paragraph]
      \step[fieldset=sortkey, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{zakon263}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{vyhlaska329}

\AtDataInput{%
  \ifkeyword{zakon263}
    {\addtocategory{zakon263}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}%
  \ifkeyword{vyhlaska329}
    {\addtocategory{vyhlaska329}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}%    
}

%Formátování polí jak v citacích (pomocí \printfield, tak v bibliografii

\DeclareFieldFormat{document}{#1 }
\DeclareFieldFormat{number}{#1/}
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{#1 Sb., }
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1 }
\DeclareFieldFormat{paragraph}{§ #1 }
\DeclareFieldFormat{article}{odst. #1 }
\DeclareFieldFormat{letter}{písm. #1)}
\DeclareFieldFormat{short}{#1 }

\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}%Vypnutí tečky na konci každé citace v bibliografii

\DefineBibliographyStrings{czech}{%Změna formy nadpisu Bibliografie na ``Reference''
  bibliography = {Reference},
}

\defbibheading{subbib}{\section{Reference v kapitole~\ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}: \nameref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment} }}
\defbibheading{zakon263}{\section{Reference ze zákona 263/2016 Sb., Atomového zákona}}
\defbibheading{vyhlaska329}{\section{Reference z vyhlášky 329/2017 Sb., o požadavcích na projekt jaderného zařízení}}

%citations

\begin{filecontents}{citations.bib}
@speclegislation{v329p10o2pa,
paragraph = {10},
article = {2},
letter = {a},
keywords = {vyhlaska329},
crossref = {v329}
}

@speclegislation{v329p11pa,
paragraph = {11},
letter = {a},
keywords = {vyhlaska329},
crossref = {v329}
}

@speclegislation{v329,
document = {Vyhláška},
short = {v.},
number = {329},
year = {2017},
title = {Decree title},
keywords = {vyhlaska329}
}

@speclegislation{z263,
document = {Zákon},
short = {AtZ},
number = {263},
year = {2016},
title = {Atomic Act},
keywords = {zakon263}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\legcite}%citace zákona
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
     \printfield{document}\printfield{number}\printfield{year}\printfield{title} %
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      [\printfield{labelnumber}]}%
    }
    {\addcomma\addspace}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parcite}%citace paragrafu
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printfield{short}\printfield{number}\printfield{year}\printfield{paragraph}\printfield{article}\printfield{letter} %
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      [\printfield{labelnumber}]}%
     }
    {\addcomma\addspace}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\chapter{Test chapter}

Test of an custom citation \parcite{v329p10o2pa}.

\clearpage

Test of an custom citation \parcite{v329p10o2pa} on new page.

\clearpage

Test of an custom citation \parcite{v329p10o2pa} on new page.

Test of citation with no article \parcite{v329p11pa}.

\clearpage

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[heading=subbib, segment=\therefsegment]

\clearpage

\chapter{Another test chapter}

Test of an decree citation for this one \legcite{v329}.

\clearpage

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[heading=subbib, segment=\therefsegment]

\clearpage

\chapter{Yet more test chapter}

Test of an law citation \legcite{z263} and again the first citation \parcite{v329p10o2pa}.

\clearpage

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\printbibliography[heading=subbib, segment=\therefsegment]

\clearpage

\printbibheading
\bibbycategory

\end{document}
```

Note: This code is when I was trying to learn to create own bibliography driver and is not optimal (a lot of time I did not know what I was doing), it is using `biblatex` to create custom lists of legislation citations and contains a mixture of czech and english. I am merely asking if there is a one command/statement that requires patching to compile with recent versions of `babel` and `biblatex`.

Comment: I can reproduce it. It is the czech option.

Comment: Here: https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3310.1579247716.2586.ctan-ann@ctan.org are stated changes for version 3.38 (which is my main suspect), mentioning changes in automatic language switching. Same problem as in question is in my main document, which is written exclusively in **czech** language.

Comment: I can confirm the error is related to a change in 3.38, which has added a line with `\IfFileExists{babel-\languagename .tex}`. This is legitimate code, however, and the error is raised, as pointed out by Ulrike, when `biblatex` attempts to patch it, because the mechanism apparently uses the ‘current’ catcode regime, not the catcode when the macro was defined (or at least, this is what it looks like).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The czech language make the hyphen `-` active and this means that biblatex no longer can prepend its code to `\select@language` at is definition text contains a non-active hyphen. You can can get around it by patching `\select@language` first, but I will suggest that babel that it avoids to use a hyphen here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage [czech] {babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@hyphen{-}
\patchcmd\select@language{-}{\my@hyphen }{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\usepackage[]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{citations.bib}

\begin{document}
blub

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating the issue. In light of your information with the hyphen shorthand causing the problem, also adding `shorthands=off` to `babel` options solves the issue.

Comment: Yes that would work too, but I was looking for a way to avoid it in case you need the shorthand ...

Comment: I agree and I highly value your answer in this issue. I merely wanted to add another option how to get rid of this error. Actually, I am using this option on most of my recent documents, since shorthands in czech babel (`-`,`"`) are (for me) causing more bad than good ... This document was a bit older and not fashioned with shorthands disabling ...

Comment: Hopefully https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/06913511f881172a0878cc19a6e5677af5885e74 should help. If you have an idea to more generally fix the correct catcode regime for the `babel` patches I'll be all ears.

Comment: @moewe well like with the beamer business, I think that instead of patching an internal command, biblatex should use an "official" hook. Which for babel means that you could look at `\AddBabelHook` and perhaps discuss with Javier if another one is needed. I don't know about polyglossia, but as development has restarted, they are probably open to suggestions too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I opened https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/970 so I don't forget about this. Ideas are of course very welcome :-)

Comment: `biblatex` 3.15, which uses the proper `babel` and `polyglossia` hooks, has been released and is available in MikTeX and TeX live now. The patches should no longer be necessary after an update.