# Problem with patching babel package

Tags: biblatex, babel, patching

I am trying to use `babel` and `biblatex` package together but I am getting following error:

> ```
> ! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'babel' package failed.
> ```

This is my code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\enquote{quote}
\end{document}
```

I would need the result look like this:

[image]

Well, it seems like I could get rid of the error when using `xpatch` package, but it works only when I delete 'slovak' option for babel package. That way the result look like this:

[image]

Please, is there any workaround for this problem? I am really stuck in this.

Comment: I don't think `csquotes` are relevant here, this seems to be an interaction between slovak-babel and `biblatex`

Comment: Loading `biblatex` before `babel` seems to solve the problem...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes, you are right, very easy solution, thank you!

Comment: I guess https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529984/35864 is related, but I couldn't get the workaround from there to fly here. Looking into it...

Answer (score 5):

It is basically the same as here [Document with custom bibliography driver compiling with babel 3.33 and biblatex 3.13a ; but not compiling with most recent package versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529984/2388). Only that it is not only the hyphen but also the apostroph.

Either disable all shorthands:

```
\usepackage[slovak,shorthands=off]{babel}
```

or patch the two offending chars away:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@hyphen{-}
\newcommand\my@apostroph{'}
\patchcmd\select@language{-}{\my@hyphen }{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\select@language{'}{\my@apostroph }{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\enquote{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both you and @moewe are probably right but I tried only the solution, which was suggested in comment by PhelypeOleinik - I loaded biblatex package before babel and everything is right :) But very interesting solutions indeed.

Answer (score 5):

### Update

The recently released `biblatex` 3.15 now uses proper `babel` and `polyglossia` hooks and no longer needs to patch package internals.

That should resolve these issues. The fixes shown below and in Ulrike's answer should no longer be necessary after a `biblatex` update.

Please update your TeX system if you are experiencing this problem.

---

This is structurally the same issue as discussed in [Document with custom bibliography driver compiling with babel 3.33 and biblatex 3.13a ; but not compiling with most recent package versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529984/35864). But for Slovak we don't only need to think about the dash (`-`) but also about the apostrophe (`'`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@hyphen{-}
\patchcmd\select@language{-}{\my@hyphen }{}{\fail}
\newcommand\my@apo{'}
\patchcmd\select@language{'}{\my@apo }{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\enquote{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image: „quote“]

---

The problem here should be resolved in the next `biblatex` release thanks to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/0f8488545292e01626dd854fee0fed8ab40adc7d and
https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/06913511f881172a0878cc19a6e5677af5885e74, but we should probably think of a better approach than patching the `babel` internals so late in `\AtBeginDocument`. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/970.

Comment: I was a minute faster ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess that's because you know what you are doing and I have to experiment before I can find the answer ...