# biblatex Error: Patching 'babel' package failed with Spanish and activeacute

Tags: biblatex, babel, compilation-error, spanish

I tried to add a bibliography to my project like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}


\begin{document}

    Esto es una referencia a \cite{knuth}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the bibliography:

```
@article{knuth,
    author = "Lawrence C. Paulson",
    title = "{Computational Logic: Its Origins and Applications}. ({English})",
    year = "2018",
    DOI = "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.04375.pdf",
    keywords = "vefication"
}
```

But it gives the following error:

> Package biblatex Error: Patching 'babel' package failed. \begin{document}

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... No errors in your provided `MWE`, can you provide you `.bib` file source?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I added the `.bib`.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but the `doi` field should only contain DOIs in the format `xx.xxxxx/xxxxx` (so without `http` and so on), not arXiv links. arXiv links can be given in the `eprint` field: `eprint = {1712.04375}, eprinttype = {arxiv}, eprintclass = {cs.LO},`. The language is usually not indicated in the `title` field. If relevant it can be given in the `language` field, though `biblatex` will by default not print the language if it coincides with the main document language. It is usually not recommended to blanket-protect the title with curly braces from case changes. ...

Comment: ... Only words that must always be capitalised (mainly names and acronyms) should be protected: `title = {Computational Logic: {Its} Origins and Applications},` should be enough (I protected the `Its` after the colon, because one often capitalises after a colon). Lastly (but this is just a comment) the entry key `knuth` seems a bit confusing for a work by *Paulson* in which Knuth isn't named once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same problem as [Problem with patching babel package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532972/35864), just this time with Spanish and in particular its `activeacute` option.

Things work without `activeacute`, so if you don't need that option, you have your solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
  Esto es una referencia a \cite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you need the option, the workaround from [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532977/35864) to  [Problem with patching babel package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532972/35864) works here as well

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\my@hyphen{-}
\newcommand\my@apostroph{'}
\patchcmd\select@language{-}{\my@hyphen }{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\select@language{'}{\my@apostroph }{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
  Esto es una referencia a \cite{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Future versions of `biblatex` will use better interfaces for the necessary patch and will not require these workarounds. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/970.

---

In any case you may want to look into saving your file in UTF-8 encoding and replacing `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (or nothing, if you have a LaTeX version that is not older than two years). With UTF-8 input it is unlikely you are going to need the `activeacute`.