# TeXstudio can't find downloaded BST file

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, miktex2.9

I downloaded [this BST file](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~martinek/latex/czechiso.html) for my LaTeX documents, however TeXstudio (using MiKTeX).
I installed it to this folder: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\bibtex`. However, TeXstudio cannot even by that way locate and use that `bibtex` style. Where should I place it? I cannot find any folder in my user folder nor in `AppData` folder that may correspond to MiKTeX.

[I found some questions with some answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/latex-cant-find-my-bst-file-how-do-i-show-it-the-way#_=_), but it doesn't look like I can find solution there. I don't even know how can I configure MiKTeX/TeXstudio.

Comment: You should **not** install files manually into the folder structure managed by your TeX system. That means that everything below `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` is off-limits for *manual* installations. The simplest solution for single-use (or occasional use) is to put the `.bst` file into the same folder as your main `.tex` file, that way it will definitely be found.

Comment: If you want a more global setup in MikTeX, you need to create a local texmf tree as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/35864. Note that within that local texmf tree your file must reside in the correct place. So your `.bst` file would have to go into `<localtexmf>/bibtex/bst/` or even better `<localtexmf>/bibtex/bst/czechiso`.

Comment: Note that the package [`biblatex-iso690`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-iso690), which implements ISO 690 following the local Czech/Slovak version of the norm, was updated only a few days ago. That package is available in MikTeX without the need for manual installations. So maybe that is a good alternative.

Comment: So how do I install the official package? Do I use `\bibliographystyle{biblatex-iso690}`?

Comment: `biblatex-iso690` comes with different styles that you use like all `biblatex` styles with the `style` option of `biblatex`. For example `\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}`. Please have a look at the documentation of `biblatex-iso690` and/or a basic `biblatex` tutorial for more details.

Comment: Okay, thanks for help. It doesn't work (https://ctrlv.cz/Lrir), but that's for [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534336/209787).